# Failed building or restoring ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I downloaded the Download **".NET Core 1.0.1 tools Preview 2"** from this link:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015

When I start my visual studio, I try to clean and rebuild the project that I created (ASP.NET Core).

When I rebuild, I get alot of errors from ASPNETCore libraries and extensions, so the next step was to try to call dotnet restore through the Package Manager Console.

However I get this error:

> "error: Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 1,
>   position 1454."

Any idea what I have forgotten?

Steps to my problem:

1. Install DotNetCore
2. start Visual Studio and create ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)
3. Clean and rebuild after the project has been created
4. If it doesn't work, go to package manager console and type in "dotnet restore"

Snippet of my problem :(

[image]

project.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you changed your nuget repository config settings in the `nuget.Config` thats why it cant find any of the nuget packages? What if you manualy run `dotnet restore` in the project directory?

Comment: did not change anything in the nuget.Config at all. I manually ran dotnet restore through powershell. Still get the same error

Comment: What are your defined dependencies, it seems to go wrong there somehwere. maybe nuget tries to read something but the response it to long and so it gets truncated, Jreader being unable to parse the string. but i would have no solution for you. (You could use fiddler to see what http requests happen when you do `dotnet restore`.

Comment: Can you update your question with your `project.json`?

Comment: ok , I have added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue!
For other people that are experiencing this (or going to).
Remember to clear the NuGet cache.

```
nuget.exe locals -clear all
```

and run

```
dotnet restore
```

on your project!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see here, you have created a .NET Core project added the support for the .NET Framework 4.6 in your project.json file:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  },
```

Which may cause some problems with dependencies compatibility. You can see in your screen you have a lot of errors like the `IHostingEnvironment` or `ConfigurationBuilder`. You have this errors because you have set your intelissence for the .NET 4.6 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5MYv.png)

One "easy" way to solve this error, is to remove the support of .NET 4.6 by replacing your `frameworks` section by:

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  }
```

You will only support the .NET Core framework and avoid compatibility errors with other frameworks (like .NET 4.6, etc...)

I guess you also forgot to add this dependency:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
```

Hope it helps.